# Big Bug at Image-Plugin

Tags: javascript, image, plugins, tinymce, insertion

I have detected a big issue at the Image-Plugin from tinymce-editor.
**VERSION: 5.6.2**
If you want to insert an Image, there will be inserted an empty image-tag. Just if you edit the Image again the Image will be inserted.
I have analysed the problem. The reason for this issue is the function **"cleanContent" in tinymce.js**. It deletes some of the html-attributes like *"src, width, height"* and so on.
I could correct this by changing one little thing in the **plugin.js** of the image-plugin.
You have to change **line 726** `editor.selection.setContent(elm.outerHTML);` to `editor.selection.setContent(elm.outerHTML,{format:"raw"});`.
In other words, I have added the "args"-parameter **{format="raw"}**, which will prevent to change the image-tag.

I think it will be useful to change this in the code for future-releases.

Comment: It would be better if you could file this as an improvement or bug in their Github Repo https://github.com/tinymce/

Answer (score 0):

In testing this in a TinyMCE Fiddle I don't see TinyMCE removing or modifying any of these attributes when you use Insert / Image and then paste a URL into dialog.

https://fiddle.tiny.cloud/s1haab

There is an image URL in that fiddle that you can use to insert the image.  The dialog correctly shows the width and height.  After clicking OK the image is in the editor with the appropriate attributes.

Here is the dialog showing the attributes:

[image: Dialog shows attributes]

Here is the resultant HTML with the attributes (HTML content shown in right side):

[image: Content contains attributes]

Comment: Add this: 
 `valid_elements : "a[href|target=_blank],b,div,br,p,h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,li,ul,img,table,tr,td,th",` ;-)

Comment: If you do that you are explicitly not allowing any attributes on the img tag. TinyMCE is doing exactly what you are telling it to do - this is not a bug.

Comment: OK, that is correct. But... if it is true, why is the Image shown, if I edit the created Image again? It has confused me a few time, because the Image was shown only after I have edited the Image again.